# Mapkit, how to detect annotations have loaded

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I want the annotations callout to popup when the pin has finished it's drop animation.  Currently I am able to simulate it with the following method:

```
- (void)showCallOut {
    [myMapView selectAnnotation:[myMapView.annotations objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
}
```

In my `viewDidLoad` is where my annotation is created

```
    [myMapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

The problem is that you simply can't callout `[self showCallOut];` after that because at run time it responds before MapKit has "acknowledged" the annotation drop.  I need to either create a delay (Would like to avoid this) or find the proper way to detect when annotations are in place and then run the `showCallOut` method.

Thanks for any help!

Thanks to aBitObvious below for providing a solution:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {
    [self performSelector:@selector(showCallOut) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the didAddAnnotationViews delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    [self showCallOut];
}
```

Make sure your map view's delegate is set.

**Edit:**
If you need to add a delay regardless, then try this instead (example with 1/2 second delay):

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(showCallOut) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
}
```

Comment: This works great!  Any quick way off the top of your head to add a delay to it?  Currently with that the CallOut is showing as the pin drops.

Comment: Great, I managed to get it but maybe your method will be improved over mine.  I'm just learning this language (3rd day on the project / using xcode / objective-c).  I'll edit my question with my method.