# Showing the Pin Information by Default

Tags: objective-c, ios, mkmapview, mkpinannotationview

I am working with `MKPinAnnotationView` annotations pins over a `MKMapView`. Into the view that I am developing, there is a map centered on a pin. When I call the view the pin drops down and if I make a click over it, it shows the annotation information (`canShowCallout = YES`). How I can get this callout just when I open the view? Without making a click over the annotation pin.

Thanks for reading.

**Edited:**

I am using this code.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    AddressAnnotation *annotation = [[[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:self.currentAnnotationCoordinate] autorelease];
    [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    [self zoomCoordinate:self.currentAnnotationCoordinate];
}

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)theMapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    // If it's the user location, just return nil.
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        return nil;
    else { // Handles the other annotations.
        // Try to dequeue an existing pin view first.
        static NSString *AnnotationIdentifier = @"AnnotationIdentifier";
        MKPinAnnotationView *pinView = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier];

        if (!pinView) {
            // If an existing pin view was not available, creates one.
            MKPinAnnotationView *customPinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationIdentifier] autorelease];
            customPinView.animatesDrop = YES;
            customPinView.canShowCallout = YES;

            // Adds a detail disclosure button.
            UIButton *rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
            [rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDetails:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            customPinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton;

            return customPinView;
        } else
            pinView.annotation = annotation;
    }

    return nil;
}


- (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)theMapView {

    AddressAnnotation *annotation = [[[AddressAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate:self.currentAnnotationCoordinate] autorelease];

    for (id<MKAnnotation> currentAnnotation in mapView.annotations) {       
        if ([currentAnnotation isEqual:annotation]) {
            [mapView selectAnnotation:currentAnnotation animated:FALSE];
        }
    }
}
```

**Edited:**

Calling `didAddAnnotationViews:` instead of `mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:` (as aBitObvious has commented), it works fine.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views {

    id<MKAnnotation> myAnnotation = [self.mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.mapView selectAnnotation:myAnnotation animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I recently answered a [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151094/getting-the-title-to-show-up-when-map-loads-with-mkmap/4151381#4151381) like this.  See if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, it works great like this. The only shadow is that the pin shows the information before touching the map (I am animating the drop down). How can I do it after?

Comment: Use performSelector:withObject:afterDelay.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083491/mapkit-how-to-detect-annotations-have-loaded/4083553#4083553).

Comment: Is there no way of knowing when the pin touches the map?

Comment: Not that I know of unless you're drawing the animation yourself.

Comment: OK. The only problem now is that I can not give you the green tick, because you only has posted comments. Anyway, thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible duplicate: [How to trigger MKAnnotationView's callout view without touching the pin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978897/how-to-trigger-mkannotationviews-callout-view-without-touching-the-pin)

You want to call `[mapView selectAnnotation:]`.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate question. I am calling the selectAnnotation: method after adding the annotation, into the viewDidLoad method, but I still need make clic over the pin to show the information.

Comment: Did you try calling selectAnnotation from (void)mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap:(MKMapView *)mapView as the first answer suggests?