# Show annotation AFTER the pin is dropped?

Tags: iphone, mkmapview

I have been checking a couple of related posts regarding the callout behaviour. I know `didAddAnnotationViews` could bring annotation view along with the pin when it starts dropping. But what I actually want is show the annotation AFTER the pin is dropped onto the map, just like when you search an address in "Maps" application on iPhone, the pin drops on the map, and then the annotation pops up. Does anyone know how to do that? Do I need to do some customisation on the annotation view? Thanks.

Comment: Try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083491/mapkit-how-to-detect-annotations-have-loaded/4083553#4083553) with a delay of about 1.0.

Comment: That works perfect! Thanks! BTW, do you know how to make the annotation disappear when I tap somewhere on the map?

Comment: Do you mean the callout?  Doesn't the map automatically close the callout when you tap somewhere else?

Comment: No, when I tap somewhere else, the callout goes away but it pops out a second later. I'm guessing it's because I set canShowCallout property of the pinAnnotationView to YES, is it?